# Re Run Feature file instead of scenario?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd

I am working on a cucumber java framework, We have build our test cases using feature files.

I have a task to implement the re run failed scenarios / feature functionality in the framework. We have created the test cases feature wise, meaning a feature file is independent but not the scenario. If we try to run the any scenario in a feature file it will fail as the scenario is not independent.

I have tried to implement the re run functionality but it support only scenario re run and not feature re run (if any scenario failed in a feature).

Is there any way to re run the feature file instead of scenario if any of the scenario failed in a feature file ?

Comment: Each scenario should be independent. This is why you cannot get it to work. Scenarios should not depend on each other for precisely the reason you posted your question.

Comment: Yes, but this has created without having initial research and now lots of features are created. Hence need to know if this can be possible or not ?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you mean by "re-run functionality"?

Comment: How are you running the tests? From the command line or from an IDE?

Comment: You can get the feature file name in the `after` hook and update the re-run file with the location. By that way it will run all the scenarios in the feature file. Just a thought!

Comment: @Greg Burghardt - cucumber has option to re run the failed scenarios in the single execution. For example, if we execute let's say 20 scenarios and due to some reason 5 failed then cucumber will re run the failed scenarios number of times (based on the count specified) in the same execution flow. To answer your second question, I am running it from IDE

Comment: @supputuri - good thought, I will try this but I am not sure if this work with my current case because I am running feature files parallel, this is generating multiple re run files and cucumber picks up all the re run txt files which has scenarios and executes them in parallel.

Comment: @DushyantPatil: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE.